# How to convert String to LongInt in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

How to convert String to LongInt in Delphi XE3? strtoInt & strToint64 are for variables of types less than LongInt.

Comment: which platform do you talk about ?

in Win32 and Apple32 platforms Int64 is 2^32 times more than LongInt. Don't remember about Win64 though

Comment: i'm talking about windows, both win32 and overloaded version for 64

Comment: LongInt is 32 bits Integer on all platforms!

Comment: @jachguate not according to the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Longint): "*On 32-bit platforms and 64-bit Windows platforms, LongInt is an 4-byte signed integer ... On 64-bit POSIX platforms (iOS and Linux), LongInt is an 8-byte signed integer*"

Comment: You're absolutely right @Remy, almost 10 years later I really don't recall why I asserted it different at the time.

Comment: @jachguate Understandable, as at the time, XE3 was the latest version, which didn't support any 64-bit Posix platforms yet, only 64-bit Windows, and `LongInt` is indeed a 32-bit integer on Win64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `...StrToInt...()` overloads that work with `Integer` values will be fine.  `Integer` and `LongInt` have the same byte size and value range on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [its signature](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt), I don't think StrToInt is for int less than longint. Integer is an alias for LongInt in Delphi by default. [Here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Internal_Data_Formats) is the table for those types.